# Python Code with infinite loop Stucks while web scraping without error message

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an python code which graps the data from url and write it  to a file in every 15 seconds. After a while, the code stops writing. But, it seems still working. It gives no error message. The time which it takes to stop is varying. Sometimes, it takes a week to stop. Sometimes, a day. Here is my code:

```
import urllib
import time
import datetime

def temp_check():
  url = "http://172.16.1.145/"  #50kw air conditioner
  try:
     f = urllib.urlopen(url)
     data = f.read()
     values50Kw = re.findall(r'<Value valueType="6" precision="1">(.*?)</Value>', str(data))
     Treturn_air50Kw= float(values50Kw[3])
  except:
     Treturn_air50Kw = 0.0
     print (datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S") + ' 50kw Temp data could not be obtained and set to be 0.0 ')

  with open("temp_data.txt", "a") as iwf:
        iwf.write(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S") + " " + str(Treturn_air50Kw))
        iwf.write("\n")
        iwf.close()

while True:
  temp_check()
  time.sleep(15)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here

```
except Exception as exception:
   print("Error encountered", exception)
   Treturn_air50Kw = 0.0
   print (datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S") + ' 50kw Temp data could not be obtained and set to be 0.0 ')
```

you should print the exception or log it to see what kind of error was encountered and not just printing some info

Comment: i edited the sample code to include the exception handling and printing